# How can I debug OSX memory card events

Tags: macos, osx-lion, kernel, debug, memory-card

I am trying to get kernel messages for memory card insertion - removal, but i don't get logs.

I issue the command "tail -f /var/log/kernel.log"

So i need to know how to increase kernel log level to be able to do such a thing.

I even installed the IOUSBFamily, but can not get extra logs.

Comment: You tagged this question osx-lion. Is it really Lion-specific (Mac OS X v10.7.x, from 2011)? The exact OS X version you care about is important, because Apple tends to tweak their logging schemes with each year's major release, so the answer for Yosemite might not apply to Lion. Did Lion still have kernel.log? Did you check system.log?

Comment: I am still using Lion. i checked the system.log and also increased kernel verbose as in this link.
http://www.cnet.com/news/boot-argument-options-in-os-x/

Comment: By the way, what do you mean by "I even installed the IOUSBFamily"? IOUSBFamily is a built-in part of OS X. Did you install some alternate version? Did you replace the built-in version with whatever other version you found? What exactly did you install?